# Линукс не видит жеский диск, а BIOS видит

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, bios, ssd

Линукс не видит жеский диск, а BIOS видит.
Лог dmesg команды в терминале.

```
 [15671.780438] usb 2-3: Product: USB3.0 to SATA Bridge
 [15671.780442] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: JMicron
 [15671.780445] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 110615238005
 [15672.001616] usb-storage 2-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
 [15672.001833] usb-storage 2-3:1.0: Quirks match for vid 152d pid 0539: 4000000
 [15672.001879] scsi host2: usb-storage 2-3:1.0
 [15672.002036] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
 [15672.013340] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
 [15673.023999] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Hitachi  HTS547564A9E384  0000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
 [15673.024472] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
 [15673.032845] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 1250263728 512-byte logical blocks: (640 GB/596 GiB)
 [15673.033109] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
 [15673.033111] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
 [15673.033356] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
 [15673.033361] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
 [15674.151101] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Cannot set link state.
 [15674.151113] usb usb2-port3: cannot disable (err = -32)
 [15674.151125] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 2
 [15674.167101] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
 [15674.167110] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
 [15674.167114] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
 [15674.167125] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
 [15674.167236] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
 [15674.167271] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
 [15674.167326]  sdb: unable to read partition table
 [15674.168043] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
 [15674.168049] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
 [15674.168059] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
 [15674.168273] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
 [15904.835346] perf: interrupt took too long (2511 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79500
 [16336.950938] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
 [16337.101349] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52f
 [16337.101356] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[16337.101360] usb 1-3: Product: USB Receiver
[16337.101364] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Logitech
[16337.104371] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:046D:C52F.0004/input/input17
[16337.104903] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52F.0004: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0
[16337.106560] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1/0003:046D:C52F.0005/input/input18
[16337.163509] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52F.0005: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input1
[16350.120564] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 6
[16400.701898] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[16400.722664] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0539
[16400.722670] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=10, Product=11, SerialNumber=5
```

Comment: Определите понятие "не видит".

Comment: Перезагрузись и давай вывод дмесг с начала. Тут про флешки в усб порту

Comment: Или диск на усб у вас?

Comment: Или умер диск или глючит конвертор усб-сата

Comment: диск на усб, если что

Comment: `[15674.167326]  sdb: unable to read partition table` — программа linux отлично видит ваш диск. а вот прочитать таблицу разделов ей не удаётся. если диск заведомо имеет разметку — меняйте диск|провода|контроллер. если не размечен — разметьте. впрочем, второе, судя по другим сообщениям — весьма маловероятно.

Comment: Провода, контакты и качество питания.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запустите `gnome-disks`. Отформатируйте и в параметрах монтирования поставьте галочку "показывать в интерфейсе"

Контроллер не может прочитать сам носитель, чаще всего неисправен контроллер или не хватает питания чтоб раскрутиться

```
Buffer I/O error on dev sdb,
```

Comment: а что делать если он не отображается в gnome-disks.

Comment: Тогда читать dmesg

Comment: добавил в описании вывод dmesg